# How to calculate the effective potential of two interacting scalar field in QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

for the potential:
$V=\lambda_h(h^2-v^2)^2+\lambda_s(s^2-w^2)^2+\lambda_{hs}h^2s^2$, where h and s are two real scalar fields and v and w are the vacuum expectation values of the two fields. The problem is there is an interaction term in the potenvial. So how to valculate the effective potential at 1 loop? for this is the sum of the connected diagrams.